# Qual a diferença entre tokens de API e tokens de acesso pessoal

Tags: token

Qual a diferença entre tokens de API e tokens de acesso pessoal?

Duvida surgida ao ler a [documentação do sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#how-it-works)

> O Sanctum permite que você emita tokens de API / tokens de acesso pessoal que podem ser usados ​​para autenticar solicitações de API para seu aplicativo.

ao usar o '/' eu entendi que são nomes diferentes para tipos de tokens diferentes

Comment: muito bom receber negativação e não saber porque --"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Na verdade são a mesma coisa, acredito que quis somente *"maximizar"* o nome.

Quando falamos em token para autenticação em APIs, todos são pessoais, ou pelo menos deveriam ser.

Trata-se de uma forma do servidor reconhecer que seu acesso é válido, fazendo analogia, como se fosse o passaporte para um evento.

São características de um token:

- Possui um hash para criptografia
- Possui tempo de expiração
- Chave secreta de conhecimento somente do servidor

Na maioria dos casos, o usuário quando faz login, recebe o JSON com token, tempo de expiração e refresh token.

Veja mais informações na documentação do [JWT](https://jwt.io/), por exemplo.

Sobre tokens: [Autenticação baseada em token - demonstração de implementação](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/events/foaf-galway/papers/fp/token_based_authentication/)

Answer (score -3):

Os tokens de acesso geralmente são transferidos para fora da URL no campo Autorização do cabeçalho da solicitação HTTP, por exemplo. Às vezes, as implementações da estrutura de autenticação personalizada fazem com que o token seja transmitido dentro de um cookie que possui as - HttpOnly, Secure e SameSite = sinalizadores ativados - ou como um cabeçalho de solicitação HTTP personalizado, como X-Auth-Token conforme documentado publicamente para o Cloud Storage SaaS da Oracle: API do Serviço de Armazenamento em Nuvem da Oracle :

É extremamente raro que cabeçalhos de solicitação HTTP e valores de cookie sejam registrados pelo navegador/software do servidor; eles também são mais difíceis de acessar programaticamente devido ao CORS (compartilhamento de recursos de origem cruzada). Em comparação, as chaves de API passadas como parâmetros HTTP GET podem ser extraídas com JavaScript do lado do cliente no DOM (Document Object Model).